# How to make a video full width and fixed height

Tags: html, css, wordpress, video

I want to make a video auto play in the webpage with full width and fixed height in WordPress. It should be similar as the video automatically play in the slider without any player but there is to be just this video auto playing again and again. Don't want to use iframe because that embeds a YouTube player but i don't need that. want to do it using CSS and HTML only.
This is the code i used but it not on the full width of the screen.

```
 <video autoplay loop style="min-width:100%;max-width:40%">
 <source src="{video-source}" type="video/mp4" />
 </video>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this also.

```css
.con{
  background-color: #000;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 40%;
}
video{
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
<video autoplay loop controls>
<source src="http://3dstudioworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this css...

```
video
{
  background:black;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: sankar i have height to be reduced and when i fix it to 40% or something else then width automatically get reduced

Comment: hey i thought height is reduced but its not how to reduce its height i'm giving height 10% height is not reduced but if i give in px then width also get reduce

Comment: i have update my code . I reduced height from 100% to 40% still height doesn't change and if i add a div outer to video and add height to it then width also gets affected.

Comment: Okay...! The video is maintaining its ratio, If you make its height small than width will automatically reduced.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116761/discussion-between-vishal-panara-and-smarttechy).